# Covariance of compound Poisson variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Please, check the below solution of the following exercise.  We are given independent random variables $N,Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,\ldots$ such that $N$ is of Poisson distribution with $EN=10$ and $P(Y_k\leq x)=1-(\frac{10}{10+x})^3$ for all k and $x\geq 0$. Let $X=(\sum_{k=1}^N \min\{Y_k,2\})\cdot 1_{N>0}$ and $Z=(\sum_{k=1}^N \max\{0,Y_k-20\})\cdot 1_{N>0}$. Calculate $Cov(X,Z).$

Comment: Why are you minusing me? :-(  The exercise is taken from the actuary exam and I've solve it however my answer is $\frac{100}{9}$ and the correct one is 25. I can show my solution but it this case it would be hard to obtain help I think.

Comment: Since you are minusing me and prevent from getting help, I show my work so far. First I calculate for $n\in \mathbb{N}$: $E(\sum_{k=1}^n \min{Y_k,2} \cdot \max{Y_k-20,0})$ $ = \sum_{k=1}^n E(\min{Y_k,2} \cdot \max{Y_k-20,0}) $ $ + \sum_{i\neq j} E(\min{Y_i,2}\cdot \max{Y_j-20,0}) $ $= n \cdot E(\min{Y_1,2} \cdot \max{Y_1-20,0}) $ $ + n(n-1) E(\min{Y_1,2})\cdot E(\max{Y_1-20,0})$.

Comment: I can't edit the above comment, so I rewrite it here: $E(\sum_{k=1}^n \min\{Y_k,2\} \cdot \max\{Y_k-20,0\})$ $ = \sum_{k=1}^n E(\min\{Y_k,2\} \cdot \max\{Y_k-20,0\}) $ $ + \sum_{i\neq j} E(\min\{Y_i,2\}\cdot \max\{Y_j-20,0\}) $ $= n \cdot E(\min\{Y_1,2\} \cdot \max\{Y_1-20,0\}) $ $ + n(n-1) E(\min\{Y_1,2\})\cdot E(\max\{Y_1-20,0\}) = (*)$.

Comment: Now the thing which I am not sure: $E(\min\{Y_1,2\} \cdot \max\{Y_1-20,0\}) $ $= E ( 2 \cdot \max\{Y_1-20,0\} \cdot 1_{Y_1>20}) = $ $2\cdot E(\max\{Y_1-20,0\}) $. Am I right here?

Comment: If so, $(*) = n  E (\max\{Y_1-20,0\}) \cdot (2- E\min\{Y_1,2\})  $ $+ n^2 \cdot E\min\{Y_1,2\} \cdot E\max\{Y_1-20,0\}$. Therefore $E(X\cdot Z) = \sum_{n \geq 0} P(N=n) \cdot E(\sum_{k=1}^n \min\{Y_k,2\}\cdot\max\{Y_k-20,0\})=$ $ \sum_{n \geq 0} P(N=n) ( n  E (\max\{Y_1-20,0\}) \cdot (2- E\min\{Y_1,2\})  $ $+ n^2 \cdot E\min\{Y_1,2\} \cdot E\max\{Y_1-20,0\})$ $ = EN E \max\{Y_1-20,0\} (2- E\min\{Y_1,2\})  $ $+ E (N^2) E\min\{Y_1,2\} \cdot E\max\{Y_1-20,0\}$.

Comment: Therefore $Cov(X,Z) = EN E \max\{Y_1-20,0\} (2- E\min\{Y_1,2\})  $ $+ Var(N) E\min\{Y_1,2\} \cdot E\max\{Y_1-20,0\}$. Now as $EN=Var(N)=10$ we have $Cov(X,Z) = 10\cdot (E \max\{Y_1-20,0\} (2- E\min\{Y_1,2\})  $ $+  E\min\{Y_1,2\} \cdot E\max\{Y_1-20,0\}) =$ $20\cdot E (\max\{Y_1-20,0\}) =(**)$.

Comment: As $\int_{20}^{\infty} (t-20)\cdot 3\cdot 10^3 (10+t)^{-4} dt $ $ = \frac{5}{9}$, we have the result $(**)= \frac{100}{9}$. Where is the mistake?